# What is the model behind the thunderbird adaptive bayesian junk filter?

Tags: algorithm, spam-prevention, thunderbird

This was surprisingly difficult to find a mathematical reference on how the Thunderbird junk filter is implemented. I found some vague statements about a "Bayesian adaptive filter" but I wasn't able to find a reference for parameters of the filter as implemented in the project.

What exactly is the algorithm? For the record I've already looked at the wikipedia articles on [Recursive Baysian Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_Bayesian_estimation) and there are a lot of "how to" articles on how to use whatever Thunderbird uses, but there aren't great references on the specific model thunderbird uses.

Comment: not sure if anyone can help here but If you feel confident, you can just [clone the project](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Thunderbird_build) since its open source and trace the implementation or maybe ask in the [forum](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=39)

Comment: I got a close vote because this question is too vague. I expected this to be closed as "off topic" or such, but I don't know how to make "what is this algorithm in this specific program" any more specific. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633975/algorithm-to-move-messages-from-inbox-to-junk-folder/1634004) also for this type of question they are off-topic since SO (stackoverflow) is all about solving code problems not giving suggestions,  or implementation, for such a question maybe [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) is a better place to post this question, but not sure check if they also accept this type of questions.

Comment: OK, that question _is_ very vague. They say "google or yahoo", which is non-specific and about a proprietary algorithm operated by a service. I've asked about one specific open source program.